# Local hard disks are not visible in my computer

Tags: windows, windows-8

I have split my hard drive(s) into six partitions. I used to be able to see all six from My Computer, but today it has has started displaying only two of them, even in the Navigation pane. However, if I enter  the name of a missing drive in the address bar, it will suddenly show up in the Navigation pane. This occurs for each "missing" volumes. Then, once I close Explorer and re-open it, the drives have "disappeared" again.

What could cause this behavior?

Comment: I am not sure about windows 8, but both windows 7 and vista have an option to hide drives. Can you check this key in the registry `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives` and add its value to the post?

Comment: @Hennes : How to do tat bro???

Comment: Goto [start], [run], type `regedit` and press enter. Answer yes to UAC. That should start the registry editor. Expand HKEY_CURRENT_USER by clicking on the +, then expand Software, Microsoft, Windows, Currentversion and click on policies. If you only see "(Default) REG_SZ (value not set)" then it is something else. If you see a key named "NoDrive" of type REG_DW then its value is a bitmask of which drives to hide. Delete the key or set the value to 0 in order not to hide any drives.